# RegEx performence issue

Tags: java, regex

I have written a regular expression to validate a name. The name can start with alphabetics and can be followed by alphabetics, numbers, a space or a `_`.
The regex that I wrote is:

```
private static final String REGEX = "([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 _]*)*";
```

If the input is: "`kasklfhklasdhklghjsdkgsjkdbgjsbdjKg;`" the program gets stuck on `matcher.matches()`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

if (matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println("Pattern Matches");
} else {
  System.out.println("Match Declined");
}
```

How can I optimize the regex?

Comment: To get the best performance ever, you should create your own String validator. Otherwise, let the JVM do the optimizations for you.

Comment: String validator? Is it a different strategy then REGEX validation?

Comment: It means parsing the String yourself and check any errors on it, more code but it can be faster than using Regex. Anyway, check the answers of people here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
private static final String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 _]*";
```

And it will match the String in a click.